# Symfony automatically appends trailing slash

Tags: symfony

Ok so here's my routing annotations:

```
/**
 * @Route("/c/{categoryName}.{extension}",
 *  name="category",
 *  schemes="http",
 *  requirements={"categoryName"=".+", "extension"="\w{3,5}"})
 * @Route("/c/{categoryName}",
 *  name="format_category",
 *  schemes="http",
 *  requirements={"categoryName"=".+"})
 *    
 */
```

For some reason when I go to `www.mydomain.com/c/some_category.htm` it automatically becomes `www.mydomain.com/c/some_category.htm/`

I have checked all the routes in my site and none are set to be `"/c/{categoryName}.{extension}/"` so I really have no idea how this is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Turns out symfony cache wasn't cleared, all working now :)